System.Drawing.Common namespace not found after installing Nuget Package
I am trying to switch out System.Drawing with System.Drawing.Common in order to upgrade my version .NET 6.0. I successfully installed the latest System.Drawing.Common v8.0.4 Nuget package (and also tried 6.0.0) but my code does not see the System.Drawing.Common namespace (see screenshot).
I have done the obvious things like delete the bin and obj folders, cleaned the solution, clear all Nuget packages, restarted VS2022, etc. but have not been able to get this to work. I am running on Windows and do not need cross-platform compatibility at this time.
Any ideas why this is not working?


Are you aware of System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows?

There is no dedicated namespace Common. All the objects in the package are placed into the System.Drawing, System.Drawing.Imaging, etc. Use Assembly explorer or inspect the sources (https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/tree/main/src/System.Drawing.Common) to find the specific namespace names

There is a breaking change in .NET 6. System.Drawing.Common package is only supported on Windows.
What you can do is to add entry into runtimeconfig.template.json or [appname].runtimeconfig.json, but this swith is only working in 6.x.x version of the library.
{
   "configProperties": {
      "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
   }
}

Eventually, you can use different graphics library as the support for System.Drawing.Common is gone.
Related info:
Breaking change: System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows
Make System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows
